# php gearman worker: дождаться выполнения функции, потом переход по очереди

Tags: php, gearman

Есть функция на php, которая отправляет смс, на выполнение этой функции требуется около 3 секунд, в течение которых модем занят и если будет вызвана функция еще раз, то она просто не отработает. Функция отправки смс вызывается в цикле для группы номеров, каждый раз в цикле выполняется doBackground(); Воркер успевает прогнать сразу все задания в очереди за эти 3 секунды и отправляется только первая смс.
Можно ли как-то настроить паузу или таймаут какой-нибудь?

PS параллельно пытаюсь в самой функции отправки смс настроить проверку состояния модема, но пока безуспешно

Comment: После отправки `sleep(3)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Решение нашлось, сам виноват, ступил.
Если воркер вертится один - то задания будут в нем выполняться по порядку, пока не завершится одно - не начнется другое, поэтому достаточно прописать `sleep(3)` в конце вызываемой воркером функции и она передаст success только через 3с после вызова функции.
До этого я додумался, но забыл, что надо перезапускать воркер заново, мало просто отредактировать файл, как я привык.

Как только я перезапустил воркер - все стало отлично